# Localization of OS dialog boxes e.g. FileOpenDialog, etc

Tags: localization, internationalization, globalization

I am localizing my winform application for french and japenese. We have fileOpenDialog used at some places, when I change the CurrentUICulture to ja-JP or fr-FR, application displays the localized screens But the dialog boxes are shown in English, i.e default OS setting.

Is it not localizable ? or there is any alternative to it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your Japanese customers are supposed to have a Japanese version of Windows, so, what to worry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Common File Dialogs and Common Item Dialogs are part of Windows itself and use the language of the underlying Windows installation. The only way to change their language is by reinstalling a different language variant of Windows.

Comment: Yeah, anyone using an application whose language is different from their OS language is going to expect this behavior. Don't worry about it.